# Question about the proof of simple algebra rule $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}} = a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a question about a proof I saw in a book about basic algeba rules. The  rule to prove is: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}} = a, \quad a \in \mathbb{R}_{\ne 0}
\end{eqnarray*}

And the proof:

\begin{eqnarray*}
1 = a \frac{1}{a} \Longrightarrow 1 =  \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}} \Longrightarrow a = a \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}} \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}} = a
\end{eqnarray*}

Why is it allowed to just replace $a$ with $1/a$? What's the explanation behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\frac{1}{a}$. Then:

\begin{eqnarray*}
1 = x \frac{1}{x} \Longrightarrow 1 =  \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}} \Longrightarrow a = a \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}} \Longrightarrow \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}} = a
\end{eqnarray*}

Better? You're right, replacing $a\to\frac{1}{a}$ is a minor abuse of notation, because they're implicitly changing the variable without telling you. But you can fix that by just letting $x=\frac{1}{a}$ at the start.

Comment: I can't see how is this any better than the original proof!

Comment: @NoChance It’s essentially the same, I just clarified why they were able to replace $a$ with $\frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: Since the OP finds it useful, it is OK.

Comment: For me it seemed a = 1/a was used and that made no sense cause the expression is obviously wrong. But by writing $1 = x\frac{1}{x}, \ x \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ and replacing the $x$ with $x = 1/a, \ a \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ I understood what was going on, thanks to auscrypt. 

Another question just popped into my mind: If $x \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ and I write $x = 1/a$ what guarantees me that $1/a \in \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$. Is it cause of the definition of the rational numbers?

Comment: It's because the real numbers form what is known as a *field* -- the multiplicative inverse of any non-zero element exists in the reals.

Answer (score 2):

$1/a$ is the multiplicative inverse $a^{-1}$ of

$a (\not =0)$,  i .e. $a^{-1}a=1$.

Need to show:

$(a^{-1})^{-1} =a;$

Since

$(a^{-1})^{-1}(a^{-1})=1$;

$(a^{-1})^{-1}(a^{-1})a=1a=a$;

$(a^{-1})^{-1}(a^{-1}a)=a;$

$(a^{-1})^{-1}1=(a^{-1})^{-1}= a$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not terribly fond of this proof.

I would rather go on defining the inverse:

- $y$ is the inverse of $x\iff xy=1$ then we write it $y=\frac 1x$.
- since everything is symmetrical $x$ is also the inverse of $y=\frac 1x$.

From there on, we have $\frac 1{\frac 1a}$ is the inverse of $\frac 1a$ which is $a$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they are replacing $a \to \frac1a$. I think the logic in the first implication is they are taking 1 over both sides. So $1/1\to 1$ on the LHS, and on the RHS, 
$$a \to \frac1a \text{ and } \frac1a \to \frac{1}{\frac1a}.$$
Similarly, in the next implication, they multiply both sides by $a$.

Answer (score 0):

I proceed in steps:

The first implication follows because the reciprocal of $1$ is $1.$ Thus, they got $$1=\frac 1a\frac{1}{\frac 1a}$$ by taking reciprocals of both sides of $$1=a\frac 1a.$$

The second implication follows since they only multiplied both sides by $a.$ This gives the last equation, which is what was to be proved.

---

A shorter way is to first define $1/a=a^{-1}.$ Then it is almost trivial to see that $$a\frac 1a=1\implies a\frac 1a\left(\frac 1a\right)^{-1}=\left(\frac 1a\right)^{-1}\implies a=\frac{1}{\frac 1a}.$$